# is it possible to plot ER Diagrams using Pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I want ER Diagram of how the tables are related to one another for a Project. 
So that the entire team can have a look at the ER Diagram of our project.I am using postgresql and to be specific pgadmin4 for administration of DB. I have defined the tables and provided necessary relationship between them. But I am not able to export the relationships as ER Diagram using PgAdmin4. I searched on google there were examples but all of them where related to the older versions(3.x). Does any one know how to do this using PgAdmin4 or I have to switch to another tool for ER Diagrams though I don't want to switch , it is my last option.

I have done ER Diagrams in Sql Server Management Studios by Microsoft. It provides a feature to do so with in a database. I am new to pgadmin4 or any version of it. But I have downloaded the latest version of it now , so if someone with prior experiance of pgadmin4 and ER Diagrams could help me with it.

I have a simple setup now which will grow as all the requirements come to us. What we have now is : Tables : A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2 . I have defined relations between all of them. But I want some tool in Pgadmin4 to give me ER Diagram of this relationship.

Comment: No, there is no way of doing that as of now.